# Declare table variable issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, declare

I want to declare a table variable and I followed the steps in [this page](https://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx) but I get error on the line `SELECT @StdRevenue;`. It seems that I need to declare the variable - which I did.

The table `Purchasing.ProductVendor`:

[image]

My code

```
DECLARE @StdRevenue TABLE
(
  ProductID int, 
  Revenue money
);

--insert values to columns
INSERT INTO @StdRevenue (ProductID, Revenue)
    SELECT ProductID, StandardPrice * OnOrderQty 
    FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor
    GROUP BY ProductID;

SELECT @StdRevenue;
```

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT * from @StdRevenue`? Its a table after all...

Comment: `select * from @StdRevenue`, not `select @StdRevenue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> SELECT * FROM @StdRevenue;

instead of

> SELECT @StdRevenue;

```
DECLARE @StdRevenue TABLE
(
  ProductID int, 
  Revenue money
);

--insert values to columns
INSERT INTO @StdRevenue (ProductID, Revenue)
    SELECT ProductID, StandardPrice * OnOrderQty 
    FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor
    GROUP BY ProductID;

SELECT * FROM @StdRevenue;
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope below queries help you....

```
Create table #temp

(
id int,
price varchar(5),
qty int
)

insert into #temp values(1,'50',1)

insert into #temp values(2,'500',4)

insert into #temp values(3,'100',6)



--Select All queries together

DECLARE @StdRevenue TABLE
(
  ProductID int, 
  Revenue money
);

--insert values to columns

INSERT INTO @StdRevenue (ProductID, Revenue)
    SELECT id, price * qty 
    FROM #temp


SELECT * from @StdRevenue;
```

----Till here

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
DECLARE @StdRevenue TABLE
(
  ProductID int, 
  Revenue money
);

--insert values to columns
INSERT INTO @StdRevenue (ProductID, Revenue)
    SELECT 1, 2

SELECT * from @StdRevenue;
```

Here you have missed to write `* from` before table name like `@StdRevenue`